# Show a bootstrap modal if option is selected or else open url

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-select, dropdown

Im trying to combine two different functions of jquery in to one function.

First funtion is when a dropdown is selected then if the "value" is a URL then jump to that URL but if the dropdown do not have a URL then check if it got a modal that it can open!

```js
$(function() {
  // bind change event to select
  $modal = $('#LoginRegister');
  if ($(this).val() === 'LoginRegister') {
    $modal.modal('show');
  } else {
    $('#designselectedchange').on('change', function() {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL
        window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select title="Select Design" class="selectpicker" id="designselectedchange" name="design">
  <option value="/frequently-asked-questions/index.html?question=client-id-register-login-view-progress-previous-order-quotations">pop up</option>
  <option value="LoginRegister">Login modal</option>
</select>

<div class="modal fade" id="LoginRegister" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login/Register</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: `if($(this).val() === 'LoginRegister'){` what `$(this)` meant to refer? It's not in a listener handler so it will be `window`..

Comment: Im a php coder not a jquery coder.. If i cut the jquery functions in two things, the URL and the Modal function each one works.. except it will run both functions..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643148/show-a-bootstrap-modal-if-option-is-selected (so this function im trying to get to work with my already existing jumping to a URL function)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user1296114/oyqrvtxb/15/ (Here is both functions separated, but the modal is opening and then running the URL that is not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler solution - test the first char for being an ID:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#designselectedchange').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
      if (val.indexOf("#") === 0) $(val).modal('show');
      else window.location = val;
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<select title="Select Design" class="selectpicker" id="designselectedchange" name="design">
  <option value="/frequently-asked-questions/index.html">pop up</option>
  <option value="#LoginRegister">Login modal</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think the : else window.location = url; should be else window.location = val;

Comment: You are of course right. Changed the var name to a better one but missed the last

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Because the problem is not with the functions themselves but with the `if` statement and the change listener.

You need to organaize the code a bit different.

1. Listen to the dropdown's change event.
2. Check what's the value and base on this, call the modal / redirect.

Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#designselectedchange').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'LoginRegister') {
      $('#LoginRegister').modal('show');
    } else {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL
        window.location = url; // redirect
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<select title="Select Design" class="selectpicker" id="designselectedchange" name="design">
  <option value="/frequently-asked-questions/index.html?question=client-id-register-login-view-progress-previous-order-quotations">pop up</option>
  <option value="LoginRegister">Login modal</option>
</select>

<div class="modal fade" id="LoginRegister" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login/Register</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Thanks 1 million bro!! Next would be to figure out just if it had a modal or not. But not for now. Its sunday!. 1000+ on your fix to it!

Comment: OOo shit.. It dont work if its already selected.. http://www.cfindo.com/ its step 4, login drop drown im trying to do this! Its my site im not trying to promote it!

Comment: :) sure. I'm AFK now but will respond you soon.

Comment: I get it.. is it possible to change $('#designselectedchange').on('change', function() { change 'change to 'select'?

Comment: i added : <option value="" selected>Make your own design</option> a empty one first!

Comment: However, why not store $(this).val() and reuse it? DRY!
`$(function() { $('#designselectedchange').on('change', function() { var url = $(this).val(); if (url) { if (url === 'LoginRegister') { $('#LoginRegister').modal('show'); } else  window.location = url; } }); });`

Comment: Yes. You're right. Usually, I prefer to solve the specific issue so OP could understand exactly what went wrong with their code. But it's a good point.